# Encrypt specific (sensitive) properties before storing on to session

Tags: c#, session, encryption

We use Redis session provider and data we store on to session may include privacy data such as DOB or membershipId.

One option (one I've implemented) is the encrypt whole class e.g. membership and decrypt on way back. This requires

**serialization of object --> encrypt --> store**.

On way back,

**decrypt --> deserialize -->convert to type**.

With this approach there can be a performance impact and newtonsoft json converter is not very smart on interface/abstract/readonly_properties.

Smarter/elegant way would be to just encrypt the specific properties before storing in session and decrypt on way back.

Would appreciate if anyone can share the implementation of 2nd option above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to create a new class for the property types you want to encrypt and then create a [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) implementation for that class, which provides encryption/decryption during the JSON serialization for the specific property. Once registered, any native object which is serialized would delegate the sensitive property serialization to the `EncryptedStringJsonConverter` class or whatever you name it, and vice-versa on decryption.